# How to let crontab take time while running

Tags: sql, bash, plsql, cron

I have a shell script that running a count in sql but when I put the script via crontab the query doesn't take enough time and the script run quickly, and no results while it should take about 25 min as it count millions of data, when I run it manually it gives the right results, so what is the reason, this is a sample of the script,

```
#!/bin/bash

COUNT=`sqlplus -s username/pass@192.168.1.10:1521/oracl << EOF

SELECT count(*) AS COUNT from table1 where
trunc(generation_timestamp)=trunc(sysdate-1);
EOF << EOF EXIT; EOF`
 
 if [[ $COUNT -ne 0 ]]; 
 then sleep 0 
 else echo "No Data in table1"> /home/data/file.txt 
 fi
```

0 * * * * sh /home/date/count.sh

Comment: Please include the crontab line. You need to make sure you are capturing (to a log file) the standard output and also standard error. There may be an execution error (most likely realted to the PATH) that you are not seeing.

Comment: I've cleaned up your code formatting a bit, but I don't understand why you have two `<< EOF` and I don't know how to format that as you intended.

Comment: 0 * * * * sh /home/date/count.sh => this is the crontab line

Comment: Is `count.sh` working from command line? Shebang is `bash` but you use `sh` later (which is not needed)

Comment: yes it is working normally with sh, the problem happened only when it run via crontab, it doesn't get outputs